# ClassNotFoundException in Nifi flow

Tags: hadoop, azure-storage, apache-nifi

Hey StackOverflow Community,

I have some problems with my Nifi flow. I made one  to take my data from my Azure blob to put them into my HDFSCluster ( still in Azure).

My configuration in the item PutHDFS in Nifi is :

[PutHDFSConfiguration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hvWXa.png)

But when I inform the field "Hadoop ressources", i have this following error:

PutHDFS[id=89381b69-015d-1000-deb7-50b6cf485d28] org.apache.hadoop.fs.adl.HdiAdlFileSystem: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.hadoop.fs.adl.HdiAdlFileSystem

PutHDFS[id=89381b69-015d-1000-deb7-50b6cf485d28] PutHDFS[id=89381b69-015d-1000-deb7-50b6cf485d28] failed to invoke @OnScheduled method due to java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed while executing one of processor's OnScheduled task.; processor will not be scheduled to run for 30 seconds: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed while executing one of processor's OnScheduled task.

How can i resolve this and put my data into my clusters.

Thanks for your answer.

Comment: Looks like you're missing hadoop libraries from your classpath

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apache NiFi does not bundle any of the Azure related libraries, it only bundles the standard Apache Hadoop client, currently 2.7.3 if using a recent NiFi release.

You can specify the location of the additional Azure JARs through the PutHDFS processor property called "Additional Classpath Resources".

Comment: The problème with this solution is, if i upgrade my NIFI, the additional azure JARs could not working after that. Actually, i look my core-site.xml file, and i think some information are missing. like the <property>
  <name>fs.adl.oauth2.client.id</name>
  <value></value>
</property>

<property>
  <name>fs.adl.oauth2.refresh.token</name>
  <value></value>
</property> but i have not the proper right in Azure to update the file...